# moodle first time login redirect to custom page

Tags: moodle

I have moodle site with **custom** signup page when new user register user redirect to the home page but then it automatically redirect to the profile edit page which is at(http://www.test.con/user/edit.php?id=46&course=1) once i update profile i can go to home page.so i want to stop this and redirect to home page.

Answer (score 1):

The automatic redirect happens when a user has required fields in their profile that still need to be completed.

Maybe you could make all required profile fields required fields in your custom signup page too, then users will always have completed them already by the time they log in for the first time.

Comment: i tested it it seems like all required fields filled when user submit signup form..

Comment: When the user logs in and is redirected to the profile editing page, are there any required fields that still need completing, or can you go straight to the home page without updating the form? If there are missing fields it will just keep redirecting you back to the profile form until all the required fields are completed. If it allows you to go to a different page without submitting the form then there must be another reason for the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to the configuration of "Default home page for users":

Go to Site Administration => Appearence => Navigation

Select other option other than "User preference".

Hope that helps!